# The Action of Nitrogen Iodide on Methyl Ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, halides, molecules

I recently encountered two old publications on action of nitrogen iodide on various compounds (Ref.1 and Ref.2). Between them, Ref.1 described the iodoform formation by methyl ketones upon treatment of the conditions:

> Ketones containing a methyl group react very readily with nitrogen iodide, iodoform, ammonia, an acid, and an amide being produced. In these reactions the methyl group appears first to be completely substituted by iodine, a tri-iodomethyl ketone being formed, which in presence of the ammonia simultaneously set free is hydrolysed to iodoform and an acid, a similar reaction between the substituted ketone and ammonia leading to the formation of iodoform and an amide.

The reactions were suggested as follows:
\begin{align}
\ce{RCOCH3 + NH3.NI3 &-> RCOCI3 + 2NH3}\\
\ce{RCOCI3 + H2O &-> RCO2H + CHI3}\\
\ce{RCOCI3 + NH3 &-> RCONH2 + CHI3}
\end{align}

This formation of iodoform is understandable. Yet, Ref.2 claimed that the authors have obtained iodoform from diethylketone (3-pentanone):

> Like the other ketones, diethylketone when treated with nitrogen iodide, yields the iodoketones, having very irritable odor. On effecting the interaction in a dilute solution, iodoform is formed in good quantity. It has been observed that as we rise higher and higher in the homologous series of the ketones, the tendency of the formation of iodoform gradually diminishes and the yields also gradually become less.

The reported method the authors had been used: $\pu{2 mL}$ of diethylketone are taken in a beaker and diluted with $\pu{150 mL }$ of weak ammonia. The mixture is warmed on the water bath, and to it, iodide solution is added when at first nitrogen iodide is precipitated, which is immediately taken up. The addition of iodine has to be continued, and finally a copious yellow crystalline precipitate deposits. This is iodoform. On recrystallization from alcohol, this has been obtained quite pure, melting at $\pu{119 ^{\circ}C}$. The yield amounts to $\pu{0.8 g}$.

I’m very curious about their claim and like to hear from your theory of mechanism.

---

**Cited References:**

1. F. D. Chattaway, R. R. Baxter, “CCX.—The Action of Nitrogen Iodide on Methyl Ketones,” *J. Chem. Soc., Trans.* **1913**, *103*, 1986–1988 (DOI: 10.1039/CT9130301986).
2. R.L. Datta, N. Prosad, “Halogenation. XVI. Iodination by Means of Nitrogen Iodide or by Means of Iodine in the Presence of Ammonia,” *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1917**, *39(3)*, 441–456 (DOI: 10.1021/ja02248a013).

Comment: In the second reaction i dont understand the significance of adding iodine continuously. If NI3 is already formed it has a property of dissociating again to I2. Then what is the reason for adding I2?

Comment: This question is hard to answer without more details from the two papers.

Comment: @Zhe hey i have a mechanism which gives us great yields of iodoform. The only problem is the details about dilution. I dont get why they dilute it.

Comment: @Som V. Tambe: I believe dilution is to prevent some unnecessary side reactions. I'm just speculating, though. :-)

Comment: @ Som V. Tambe: I believe the following statement in the publication may give what they meant by "the addition of iodine has to be continued": *...by means of a potassium iodide solution of iodine in conjunction with liquor ammonia, which represents nitrogen iodide in the nascent state...* However, in the first paper they  had prepared nitrogen iodide by adding a solution of iodine monochloride in hydrochloric acid to strong ammonia where nitrogen iodide had formed as black precipitate.

Comment: @Zhe: Both papers did not indicate any mechanistic aspects. The first paper described the formation of iodoform from acetophenone and acetone with set of equations I have given in my question. The second paper described the iodination of phenol, nitrophenols, cresols, thymol, etc. In addition, they also described the idoform formation of ketones including methyl ketones and 3-pentanone. Preparation method only.

Comment: How do the authors in reference 2 know they have 3-pentanone instead of 2-pentanone using analytical techniques available in 1917? The boiling points are the same.

Comment: @KG3: By 1917, it they should be able to distinguish these two compounds by their physical and chemical properties. Also, they have checked the homologous compounds to 3-pentanone, such as 3-hexanone, etc.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Which physical and chemical properties are you referring to? The boiling point and refractive index are not distinguishing. There was no NMR, IR, or mass spec available to the authors in 1917. As the haloform reaction is a classical method for identification of _methyl_ ketones it is most probable that the authors mistook 2-pentanone for 3-pentanone, which would be easy to do with the available analytical techniques of the time.

Comment: @ KG3: I cannot pinpoint how they distinguish those chemicals. Yet, chemistry is in prictice way before 1917. For example, how would you think Claisen recognized the rearrangement without NMR or IR or MS? It's not easy, but they have done that and results are very fruitful.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne you are completely missing the point. The proposed reaction in reference #2 contradicts the entirety of the literature on the haloform reaction since 1870. Either we should (A) discard all subsequent literature examples that utilize the haloform test to identify methyl ketones as incorrect (B) presume Datta & Prosad made incorrect but completely understandable assumption. If you're going to make extraordinary claims you must supply extraordinary evidence. Claisen did. Datta and Prosad did not.

Comment: @KG3: Please read about my comment "*...very curious about their claim..*" part at the end. Doesn't it say something. I want to know if someone else come up with a reliable mechanism. I already knew there may be a mistake. But I cannot single handedly waive someone else's work. As a community, we all need to agree.

Comment: @KG3 and Mathew: My first thought about diethylketone giving CHI3 was that they had 2-pentanone. I am incredulous with the statement, "It has been observed that as we rise higher and higher in the homologous series of the ketones, the  tendency of the formation of iodoform gradually diminishes and the yields also gradually become less." It is conceivable that 3-pentanone is converted to the 2-iodide, hydrolyzed to the acyloin and oxidized to 2,3-pentanedione that gives iodoform. This procedure is improbable for higher symmetrical ketones. Of course, 2-pentanone is still a option.

Comment: @user55119: I appreciate your comment. It's make sense. I'll look at relevant results.